# Examples illustrating the difference between closed and bounded sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Intuitively for me, it seems as if closed sets are bounded, especially considering closed sets contain all limit points. But I know this isn't the case, because $ℝ$ is closed (and open) and is not bounded.

Is this the only case of a closed set not being bounded? Can anyone provide an example that further illustrates the difference between closed and bounded?

Comment: One thing it might be handy to remember is that a closed set is the complement of an open set. So like, the complement of any open ball, for instance, is closed.

Comment: An easier way to describe bounded (for me) is that the set lies in a closed ball.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The integers as a subset of $\Bbb R$ are closed but not bounded.

Comment: Do you mean ℤ? So, would every finite set be closed and bounded?

Comment: yes this is because each singleton is closed and the finite union of closed sets is closed again

Comment: Finally finite implies bounded

Comment: @sugataAdhya I was referring to singletons in $\mathbb{R}$ not in any space

Answer (score 43):

We cover each of the four possibilities below.

Closed and bounded: $[0,1]$

Closed and not bounded: $\cup_{n\in Z}[2n,2n+1]$

Bounded and not closed: $(0,1)$

Not closed and not bounded: $\cup_{n\in Z}(2n,2n+1)$

Answer (score 6):

$$\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x\geq 0\}$$

Also note that there are bounded sets which are not closed, for examples $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks, can you please see my reply to Amr?

Comment: Yes, every finite set is closed and definitely bounded.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Check out my comment above.

Comment: @Sugata: Real analysis is done in the real numbers with the standard topology.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: 'General-Topology' is tagged with the question. But as far as your solution is concerned it's all right.

Comment: @Sugata: I added the general topology tag. It was originally tagged only with real analysis tag.

Answer (score 5):

In $\mathbb R^n$ every **non-compact closed** set is unbounded.